# How to set SQL Code Style in IntellijCE on MacBook

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.3 version on my MacBook.
I want to reformat SQL code but I dont see any SQL Code Style.
How can I add a new code style in IntelliJ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is available only in [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).